# how to replace the content between the strong tags with bold text in android

Tags: java, android, html

I'm parsing html content with the Jsoup library and I want to transform the content between the `strong` tag in bold text in android; here is my attempt:

```
paragraph.html().replace("<strong>(.+?)</strong>", new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD).toString());
```

I've already tried to use `Html.fromHtml` but it doesn't work..

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this solution:
String yourString;
yourString= yourString.replace("<strong>", "<strong><b>");
yourString= yourString.replace("</strong>", "</b></strong>");
String newString = Html.fromHtml(yourString);

Comment: I've already tried to use Html.fromHtml but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to solve my problem thanks to Rami answer:

```
String myParagraph = paragraph.html(); 
myParagraph = myParagraph.replace("<strong>", "<strong><b>"); 
myParagraph = myParagraph.replace("</strong>", "</b></strong>"); 
String newString = Html.fromHtml(myParagraph);
```